# Can someone keep a list of the best April 1st questions?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

There are already some really great ones (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558252/help-building-a-website-using-punched-cards)), but I don't want to keep hitting Refresh all day looking for a good laugh... is anyone keeping a simple list of the funny questions?

Comment: Note: the obvious solution is a special tag, but then someone (moderator?) has to manually keep an eye out and tag them all.

Comment: @Matt, ok, for every question submitted here I will make sure it is tagged with April Fools..

Comment: would it be better to simply tag them as humo(u)r ? There are funnies posted on other days

Comment: I already retagged a few. The april-fools tag is left over from last year, when Jon Skeet started a couple of days early.

Comment: To all volunteers:  it would be great if people could tag (or provide links to) SF and SU questions as well (assuming there are any).

Comment: ...you presume that there *were* good 1 April questions...

Answer (score 3):

[How to deal with a program that has become self aware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561112/how-to-deal-with-a-program-that-has-become-self-aware)

Answer (score 3):

[Mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558071/help-with-design-for-vacation-tracking-system-c-net-access-webservices-soa-exc) didn't get enough views to reach escape velocity (probably not a catchy enough title), but it did manage to punk a few people and has a 14% view-to-upvote rate, which is pretty good in my book. ;)

Comment: This is a work of art, and I commend you.  Well done!

Comment: Great work, even if it did remind some of us of real projects.

Comment: I tagged it as humor. The joke questions that have survived seem to have this tag. Hope you don't mind. No comment on how funny (or not) it is.

Comment: @Yar; No, I don't mind, although I think you may be mistaken. It's not so much about the tags, it's that the popular questions were more *accessible* (generic geek humour), whereas this one was targeted toward a specific group of developers familiar with a lot of the design anti-patterns and especially the classic TDWTF articles.  I do have to admit, the C/C++ question managed to be pretty funny without being lowest-common-denominator.

Comment: I'm not complaining, mind you - I'm not above petty one-liners or playing to the crowd when the moment seems right, I did this because it was fun to make and to admire the gradual but steady progression to total insanity in the finished product. ;)

Answer (score 2):

LOGO! =D

[Turtles and Unicorns are finally compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562400/how-do-i-draw-a-figure-using-logo)!

Answer (score 2):

[Should I redesign my code when my colleague says so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563045/should-i-redesign-my-code-when-my-colleague-says-so)

Hilarious, especially so for C, C++ programmers and fans of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's been tried: [What question would you have asked as an April Fool?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/what-question-would-you-have-asked-as-an-april-fool)

Seems to have lost steam this year, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try these links:

- [[april-fools]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools)
- [[always-unicorn-in-iceland]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-unicorn-in-iceland)
- [[unicorns]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns)
- [[humor]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor)
- [[fun]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we agree to tag them - Isn't that the point of communities ?
I propose "best-of-SO"

Comment: or as `AprilFoolsDay-2010`

Comment: Just use "fun" - it's an existing tag for these sorts of questions.

Comment: So is "humor" 8-]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just added my own joke post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561960/alternate-payload-encoding-for-the-binary-lexical-octet-adhoc-transport-protocol

Please, be gentle.